# When to alloc/init an ivar, and when not to

Tags: objective-c, ios, instance-variables

All,

In Apple's sample code "DateCell"

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html

the ivar "pickerView" is declared in MyTableViewController.h like this:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
@private
    UIDatePicker *pickerView;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;    // this button appears only when the date picker is open

    NSArray *dataArray;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pickerView; 
...
```

It is synthesized in the class file MyTableViewController.m like this:

```
@implementation MyTableViewController

@synthesize pickerView, doneButton, dataArray, dateFormatter;
...
```

When this app runs, I can insert `NSLog(@"%@",pickerView)` into ViewDidLoad and see that, sure enough, the ivar pickerView is real and has a value. Nowhere, though, does this class alloc/init pickerView. And that's the root of the question: how's it getting done if it's not being done explicitly?

Well, I naively copied this stuff to my code into my RootViewController.h and .m files figuring I could do the same, but pickerView stubbornly remains uninitialized (and my NSLog calls return "(nil)" as its value) no matter what I try short of explicitly alloc/initing it. Certainly RootViewController is being instantiated, or the RootView wouldn't be showing up, right? So shouldn't my pickerView be coming along for the ride just as it does for Apple?

So... do I have to manually alloc/init the pickerView instance variable? If so, where's Apple doing it? Or how are they doing it somehow otherwise?

I think I'm missing something very basic here, but I have no idea what it is. I can't see anything in Interface Builder or XCode that looks different between mine and theirs, but I've got tunnel vision at this point and can't see anything clearly anymore.

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IBOutlet modifier on this line is the key...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pickerView;
```

IBOutlet is a decorator that indicates that the object will be hooked up/connected/initialised when the corresponding xib (Interface Builder) file is loaded.  The sample application you're looking up will contain a UITableViewController is a xib which has a connection to a UIPickerView.

You can either go the route of creating your own custom xib file and wire to an instance of UIPickerView or you can manually initialise the picker yourself.

Comment: I'll bet you're not surprised to hear that you nailed the answer! The connection is between a UIDatePicker in the MainWindow.xib file and the MyTableViewController class, so when I was looking around in the MyTableViewController nib file... nothing to be seen! Is there any reason that Apple would choose to put the UIDatePicker into the MainWindow nib file instead of the MyTableViewController nib file? That seems kinda' disconnected, but there may be a sound design pattern at work here that I'm not aware of. (And, being quite the n00b, that's highly likely.) Thanks again, Matt!

Comment: I took a quick look at the sample and you're exactly right about the weird use of MainWindow.xib.  Personally I would have set the connection in the MyTableViewController nib - that feels like the right scope.  The only reason for pushing it up to MainWindow would be to set a connection with one of the application level objects UIApplication or its delegate, which this example is not doing.  Glad you're sorted though :)

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder (nib or xib) treats automatically IBOutlet ivar with connection of components.

> IBOutlet is a special keyword that is
>   used only to tell Interface Builder to
>   treat an instance variable or property
>   as an outlet. It’s actually defined as
>   nothing so it has no effect at compile
>   time.

- [Your First iOS Application - The
  View Controller Interface
  Declaration, Making Connections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html)
- [Interface Builder User Guide -
  Defining Outlets and Actions in
  Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/CodeIntegration/CodeIntegration.html)

Comment: Thanks for these links--I'm still getting familiar with the documentation and have been looking for this kind of Apple-provided info. I have read other books on the subject, but all of them teach by example and don't necessarily explain Apple's thought process behind the toolset and designs.